# What is an overview of Pentecostal views on killing in war?

Tags: pentecostalism, war, killing, just-war-theory

I've often heard from skeptics of Christianity, "Look at the many atrocities done in the name of Jesus in places like the Crusades. How can you claim that Jesus is loving?" I know that these claims are preposterous. Look at all the many more wonderful good works done in Jesus' name! But that's beside the point. The Old Testament often speaks of wartime and killing those who occupied Israel in ancient times, but war is rarely mentioned in the literal sense in the New Testament.

What is an overview of Assemblies of God / Pentecostal views of killing in war, or of war in general?

Comment: War is not a topic that is central to pentecostalism so there's no reason to think that there is only one view, or even one dominant view. Asking about the position of one denomination, like the Assemblies of God, could be good, but you'd have to specify the country because many countries have a denomination of that name, and I don't think there are strong ties between them all.

Comment: Per @curiousdannii's comment, I have edited this to make it an overview question, which should be more answerable within C.SE topic guidelines.